# SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM

Tags: apache-spark

Submitting a simple Spark pipeline:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class com.example.ExamplePipeline --master local pipeline-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
...
17/01/11 12:34:24 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:82)
org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:874)
org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:81)
org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.<init>(JavaStreamingContext.scala:140)
com.example.ExamplePipeline.createExecutionContext(ExamplePipeline.java:72)
com.example.ExamplePipeline.exec(ExamplePipeline.java:115)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1641)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:2257)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:2239)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.assertNoOtherContextIsRunning(SparkContext.scala:2239)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.setActiveContext(SparkContext.scala:2325)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:2197)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:874)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.<init>(JavaStreamingContext.scala:140)
    at com.example.ExamplePipeline.createExecutionContext(Exampleipeline.java:72)
    at com.example.ExamplePipeline.exec(ExamplePipeline.java:115)
    at com.example.ExamplePipeline.main(ExamplePipeline.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/01/11 12:34:24 INFO ReceiverTracker: Sent stop signal to all 1 receivers
17/01/11 12:34:24 INFO StreamingContext: Invoking stop(stopGracefully=false) from shutdown hook
```

it looks there is another context running, and so it's stopped. I can't find what else is running, but this used to work in the same environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have only one SparkContext instance, unless you set `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true` (but it's not recommended - it's for tests, not production)

If you do:

```
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, window);
```

Spark will create new SparkContext and then StreamingContext, that will be using created SparkContext. If you have created your SparkContext before StreamingContext, there will be an exception thrown. As far as I can see from the stacktrace, you are using this constructor

To avoid this exception you can run:

```
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkContext, window);
```

Comment: @t-gawęda, code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722984/sparkexception-using-javastreamingcontext-getorcreate-only-one-sparkcontext-m